# Is calling ensure_future the right way to wrap up the results of coroutines?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm still a bit unsure about when to use `ensure_future` and I was wondering if this is a situation where I would want/need it.

Consider the following code

```
import asyncio


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


async def do_work(count):
    for i in range(count):
        if i % 10000 == 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    print(count)
    return i


async def do_batch_work():
    res1 = do_work(100000)
    res2 = do_work(100)
    await asyncio.wait([res1, res2])
    return res1, res2


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    res1, res2 = loop.run_until_complete(do_batch_work())
    print(res1.result())
    print(res2.result())
    loop.close()

main()
```

This prints:

```
100
100000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "more_async.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "more_async.py", line 26, in main
    print(res1.result())
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'result'
```

The async code runs as expected and prints out in the expected order but the `loop.run_until_complete(...)` doesn't give me access to the underlying results because the `coroutine` object doesn't seem to have a way to get to the results.

I can fix that by changing the method as follows

```
async def do_batch_work():
    res1 = asyncio.ensure_future(do_work(100000))
    res2 = asyncio.ensure_future(do_work(100))
    await asyncio.wait([res1, res2])
    return res1, res2
```

By calling `asyncio.ensure_future(...)` I make sure to get `Task`s back where I can call `result()` on.

I wonder, is that the right way to handle it? Do I need to use `ensure_future` if I care about the result of that coroutine or is there another way that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async def do_batch_work():
    res1 = do_work(100000)
    res2 = do_work(100)
    await asyncio.wait([res1, res2])
    return res1, res2
```

`res1` and `res2` are only coroutines in that example, not `Future` objects, therefore no result attribute. When you use `ensure_future()` `res1` and `res2` are now `Future` objects, which is why you can access the result attribute. `wait()` works the same in both cases and the results in both codes are equally generated, it's just that your function hadn't return the correct objects.

If you want to modify your first example, the `Future` objects that you wanted are returned as the first item by `wait()`.

```
async def do_batch_work():
    res1 = do_work(100000)
    res2 = do_work(100)
    (res1, res2), _ = await asyncio.wait([res1, res2])
    return res1, res2
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is quite good - it works exactly as it should, and I think asyncio still doesn't have some strong standards being developed. But if you just want to run coroutines in parallel, there is another way, and it is seen more frequently.

It is [asyncio.gather()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather).

Gather's doc is quite self-explanatory, it returns future with list of results, and here is an example of your code with it:

```
async def do_batch_work():
    res1 = do_work(100000)
    res2 = do_work(100)
    return await asyncio.gather(res1, res2)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    res1, res2 = loop.run_until_complete(do_batch_work())
    print(res1)
    print(res2)
    loop.close()
```